# how to handle Multiple Orwhere in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

I'm working in Laravel 5 and am using the *Orwhere* clausule, my code to consult is this:

```
$estudiantes= Usuario::
        where('rol', '=', 'ESTUDIANTE')
            ->whereHas('perfil', function($query) use ($data){
                if($data!="")
                    $query->Where('doc_identidad', '=' ,$data)
                        ->orWhere('nombres','like','%'.$data.'%')
                        ->orWhere('apellidos','like','%'.$data.'%');
                dd($query);
            })->get();
```

So, I want to filter every *Usuario* with rol *ESTUDIANTE* that works very fine, then I want to filter which of these have *doc_identidad* or *nombres* or *apellidos* like you see, I have a `dd($query)` to see the tree of the query, and I noticed that the first *where* uses *and* instead of *or*. This is the tree:[image]

So, I have the next:
where1 and where2 or where3 or where4

and I want:
where1 and (where2 or where3 or where4)
so, how should I do it? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

where1(a=1) and (where2(b=1) or where3(c=1) or where4(d=1))

```
Model::where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('a', '=', 1);
})->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('b', '=', 1)
          ->orWhere('c', '=', 1)
          ->orWhere('d', '=', 1);
});
```

Comment: Hi, that's almost the same thing that I have, with the exception that I have a whereHas that I really need.thanks